# Why does my pdo fetch_OBJ return Fatal error: Undefined class constant

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

> Fatal error: Undefined class constant 'Fetch_OBJ' in C:\xampp\htdocs\index.php on line 23

```
<?php

try {
  $pdo = new PDO('mysql:host=127.0.0.1;dbname=neon', 'root','');
} catch (PDOException $e) {
  die('could not connect.');
}

$statement =$pdo->prepare('select * from team');
$statement->execute();

$sql = $statement->fetchAll(PDO::Fetch_OBJ);

var_dump($sql[0]->Name);

require 'index.view.php';
?>
```

Comment: use all capitals ie `fetchAll( PDO:: FETCH_OBJ );`

Answer (score 1):

FETCH_OBJ will be the constant name